# How do I manipulate constraints in constraint derivatives of Legendre transformations?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I having trouble understanding the constraint derivative in the highlighted part of the picture below, which allows to convert the one adimensional thermodynamical relation into its dimensional counterpart.
Specifically ,when doing the derivative of the product, done with $\beta P = const$ ,why do the three derivates that follow  have different constraints: one is with $ P=const$, another one with $\beta = const$ and another one with $\beta P=const$. I would have written all of them with the same initial constraint: $\beta P=const$, how do I realize how to change the constraint in each case?

For example for the case of the derivative with respect to $\beta$  they write $ P=const$, but that seems wrong because when doing the derivative with respect to $\beta $we are varying $\beta$(because we're calculating how something varies when $\beta$ varies) and if P is constant, then $\beta P$ cannot be constant, which was the original constraint

Considering the following Legendre transformation:
[image]

From this, it follows that
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a misunderstanding in the meaning of leaving $P$ and $\tilde P$ as a constant.
It is a general misunderstanding in the framework of thermodynamics, and a common mistake for many students.

When writing $\left(\frac{d \mathcal G (\beta, \tilde P)}{d \beta} \right)_{\tilde P = const.}$ you don' t mean that $\tilde P$ is a constant. You mean that the partial derivative of function $\mathcal G (\beta, \tilde P)$ is taken over the variable $\beta$ AND that the two independent variables of $\mathcal G$ are $\beta $ and $\tilde P$. So the subscript $\tilde P = const.$ only tells you WHICH is the second variable.

The function $G(\beta, P)$ is NOT a function of $\tilde P$, but a function of $P$ instead. So, you need to perform a change of variables. You need to switch from the system of independent variables $(1) \{ \beta , \tilde P \}$ to the system $(2) \{ \beta, P \}$.

Consider performing the transformation $\{ \alpha, \tilde P \} \rightarrow \{ \beta, P \}$. The derivatives change becoming:
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\right)_{\tilde P = const.} \rightarrow \left( \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial \alpha} \right)_{\tilde P = const.} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}\right)_{P = const.} + \left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial \alpha}\right)_{\tilde P = const.} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial P}\right)_{\beta = const.} 
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde P}\right)_{\alpha= const.} \rightarrow 
 \left(\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial \tilde P}\right)_{\alpha = const.} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}\right)_{P= const.} + \left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial \tilde P}\right)_{\alpha= const.} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial P}\right)_{\beta = const.} .
\end{equation}

In the specific case, the transformation is :
\begin{align*}
&\beta = \alpha
\\
&
P = \tilde P / \alpha,
\end{align*}

and we are switching from $\mathcal G (\alpha, \tilde P) = \beta G(\beta, P)$. Thus, we write:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left(\frac{d \mathcal G (\alpha, \tilde P)}{d \alpha} \right)_{\tilde P = const.}  = & \left(\frac{d \beta G (\beta, P)}{d \alpha} \right)_{\tilde P = const.} 
\\
= & G(\beta, P)
\\+& 
 \beta \left[  \left( \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial \alpha} \right)_{\tilde P = const.}  \left(\frac{d G (\beta, P)}{d \beta} \right)_{P = const.} + \left(\frac{d P}{d \alpha}\right)_{\tilde P = const.} \left(\frac{d G (\beta, P)}{d P} \right)_{\beta = const.}   \right].
\end{split}
\end{equation}
If you plug the transformation above in this relation you find the highlighted relation.

Comment: The second paragraph seems to be missing a verb which is preventing me from understanding the sentence:   "When writing $\left(\frac{d \mathcal G (\beta, \tilde P)}{d \beta} \right)_{\tilde P = const.}$ you don' t mean that $P$ is a constant. You mean that the partial derivative of function $\mathcal G (\beta, \tilde P)$ over the variable $\beta$ (? missing verb)...."

Comment: And did you mean ..."You don't mean that $\tilde P$ is a constant" instead of  "You don't mean that $P$ is a constant"?, because there is no explicit P variable there

Comment: Also I still don't get why  for example in the first transformation equation, the second derivative that shows up:  (   $ \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial \alpha})_{\tilde P = const.}$ is done at $\tilde P = const$ but the term that is multiplying is done 
 at $ P = const $

Comment: Now I edit the answer, sorry for the mistakes

Comment: Answer edited. To answer your third comment, read carefully the text. The subscript does not mean that one variable is constant, but simply tells you where is the dependency in the expressions you are considering. If it is not clear, you should refer to some Calculus textbooks where they explain how to transform partial derivatives.

Comment: If the subscrit doesn't indicate the variable is held constant, why is the word const explicitly written there? To know what are the other variables I just look inside the parenthesis $\mathcal G (\beta, \tilde P)$, I don't think the purpose of the subscript is that, and I've heard the professor reading it out loud as  "at   constant <subscrit_variable> "

Comment: So, it is told to be constant because physically you are varying $\beta$ and not $P$, letting $P$ be a constant, and this is correct. This is the idea of partial derivatives as well. But this saying is misleading. In fact, it is hard to understand the math I showed you, because of this confusion of what is constant and what not. Mathematically, you are performing a change of variables. The step I showed are coherent and give the correct solution, thus they are right. This thing of being a constant and being a variable becomes clearer with time, you simply need to get used to that.

Comment: Remember, when you perform partial derivatives, let's say $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$, you should specify that $y$ is a constant in the derivation process $\left(\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\right)_{y = const.}$. Mathematicians don't specify this, because it is redundant. On the other hand, in physics, you may face different situations where some variables are fixed and others are not. To keep track of it, this saying was introduced, but it is extremely misleading when doing calculations.